# no arbitrage condition for paylater option

Tags: options, option-pricing, finance

a paylater option has the folowing payoff: $(S_{T}-K)_{+}-P1_{S_{T}>K}$.
To determine the fee P that the option holder must pay, we must write the non arbitrage condition. Why is it this: 
$E_{Q}[(S_{T}-K)_{+}-P1_{S_{T}>K}]=0$ ? I mean it would say the no arbitrage condition consists to write that the price of a paylater option is 0 ??

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of an option is the premium that is paid to own this option. For this paylater option, since nothing is paid upfront, the value of the option is zero. That is,
\begin{align*}
e^{-rT}E\big((S_{T}-K)^{+}-P1_{S_{T}>K}\big)=0,
\end{align*}
or
\begin{align*}
E\big((S_{T}-K)^{+}-P1_{S_{T}>K}\big)=0.
\end{align*}

Comment: Ah ok thank you I didn't well understand the definition of the paylater option.

Comment: I will treat this as an exotic option. Its payoff is given by $(S_T-K)^+-P1_{S_T>K}$ with zero cost initially. Thanks for adopting my answer.

Comment: Yes this is exactly that (the fact that it's intially zero cost troubled me)

Comment: The initial zero cost simply means that the value is zero.